# Do not trigger touchstart if user scrolls by element

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have the following code targeting mobile devices:

```
$('.class').on('click touchstart', function(){
```

It works but does not allow scrolling. So if user touches the element and aims to scroll, it'll be triggered regardless.

What is the approach here? Also, why is it that on some elements, `click` works, and on others, we are required to include `touchstart`?

Comment: @IncredibleHat On various instances, simple `click` doesn't work without adding `touchstart`. If you search for it on SO, you can see tons of threads about it.

Comment: Ah, well, weird. I guess I've never hit the edgecase need. Good to know then for future odd situations where something stops working and I scratch my head wondering why ;)

Comment: I am also very eager to know about this as I've had a similar issue. +1